# jQuery select an eq target from other list that's not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, dom

Can't get the "not" to work. When I click on a list, I want to use that index to target a list of absolute images. The chosen background image stored in a list will not fade out but the rest will. The chosen one will stay.

```
$('.accordion-item').click(function(){
    var index=$(this).index();
    var rotationImage = $('.image-rotation li');
    rotationImage.not('eq(index)').fadeout;
    rotationImage.eq(index).fadeIn();
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/rezasan/pen/oLPYVr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's see ...

1. you should write `:eq()` no just `eq()`
2. you have to escape `index` in the `string` of `:eq()` correctly
3. it is `.fadeOut()` not just `.fadeout`

Everything else works fine in general. :)

```
$('.accordion-item').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    var rotationImage = $('.image-rotation li');
    rotationImage.not(':eq('+ index +')').fadeOut();
    rotationImage.eq(index).fadeIn();
});
```

And just to be complete, you could even do this in a single chain and don't need `not()` at all:

```
$('.accordion-item').click(function(){
    $('.image-rotation li').fadeOut().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
});
```

**[Working example.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkJbKB)** (*updated codepen*)

Comment: I missed out the +index+ and yes it's fadeOut(). Thanks so much @eisbehr. You've been a great help.

Comment: You're welcome, @RezaSan! I've just updated my answer to show you an even shorter way to do your work.

Comment: That's even shorter. So does that mean I do not have to cache to li? I'm just afraid browser will crash if I don't cache them into a variable first? What do you think?

Comment: In this case it makes no difference! A chain does only get the elements one time too, like a variable. In fact, my shorter example should be even faster, because it don't uses `not()` to filter. Only other thing you can do (*but not have to*), is to declare a variable containing the elements on the outside of your `click` event handler and reuse it. @RezaSan

Comment: Ok noted. Thanks once again guru @eisbehr. *Salute.